# fgetc giving me garbage

Tags: c, file, io

I wrote a simple program to output text from an ASCII file to the command line, but I am getting garbage characters back. Here the relevant bit of my code:

```c
void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char *filename;
    ... [filename is defined here as the command-line argument]
    FILE *fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (fptr == NULL) {
        printf("Error: no such file %s!\n", filename);
        exit(1);
    } else {
        int c;
        while(c = fgetc(fptr) != EOF) {
            putchar(c);
        }
        fclose(fptr);
    }
}
```

When I run this code using a simple test file which contains a line of text I get a bunch of garbage symbols back.

Comment: Your statement is equivalent to `while( c=(fgetc(fptr) != EOF))` so you need parentheses like this `while( (c=fgetc(fptr)) != EOF )`

Comment: `while (c=fgetc(fptr) != EOF ) {`: You didn't care precedences of `=` and `!=`. Try this: `while ((c=fgetc(fptr)) != EOF) {`.

Comment: ...otherwise `c` will always be 1 and once (finally) 0.

Comment: So because of my poor syntax the pointer was never being increment to the next character? I see. But I wonder why this didn't cause an infinite loop. *edit: no I interpreted that wrong. I guess fgetc uses its own internal pointers to get to the end of the file without modifying the argument pointer and int c was always evaluating to 1

Comment: Yeat again, a compound expression goes wrong:(   Write simple code, write code that is easy to test, write code that is easy to debug.   You then will probably get working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operator *!=* has precedence over operator *=*, so your variable *c* is being assigned with the value of the comparison (*fgetc(fptr) != EOF*). To fix that you have to put parenthesis around the assignment:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    assert(argc == 2);
    FILE * fptr = fopen(argv[1], "r");
    assert(fptr);
    int c;
    while((c = fgetc(fptr)) != EOF) putchar(c); 
    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

(Note that I asserted the values just for the sake of readability. Since your program interacts with the user, you are doing fine by manually checking them and printing specific error messages.)

Comment: Why all the other non-relevant changes to his code?