# Copying a string from input.txt to output.txt using fopen, fgetc, fput and fclose funtion

Tags: c, fopen, fclose, fgetc

I'm trying to simply copy a string by reading it from input.txt and copy it to output.txt. The issue I'm facing is the output file dosen't contain any of the letters of the input file. It contains only  letters.

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void) {
    char input[45] = "S:/Master/M_32561/9000_A/B11-01/input.txt",               
         output[45] = "S:/Master/M_32561/9000_A/B11-01/output.txt";

    FILE *dtzgr_0,  /* Input-Pointer */
         *dtzgr_1;  /* Output-Pointer */

    dtzgr_0 = fopen(input, "r");

    if(dtzgr_0 != NULL) {
        dtzgr_1 = fopen(output, "w");

        int c;

        while(c = fgetc(dtzgr_0) != EOF)
            fputc(c, dtzgr_1);

        fclose(dtzgr_1);
    }
    else
        printf("Can't read %s.", input);

    fclose(dtzgr_0);
}
```

[image: output.txt]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fgetc giving me garbage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48400532/fgetc-giving-me-garbage)

Comment: And another example of why stuffing assignments into a conditional clause is bad.  `while(c = fgetc(dtzgr_0) != EOF)` is bad code not because you left out a set of parenthesis (we all create bugs like that...), but because there's too much going on in that one statement for you to be able to see what's wrong.  Splitting the assignment and the check of the result into separate lines makes for much more readable, understandable code.  Anyone who claims "brevity of code" is an advantage here is just cargo-cult programming.

Comment: Thx xing for your explaination. Andrew, I don't think it is bad to put assignments into a conditional clause. I was not aware of the valance of operators. Once you're you could write short code. I agree in terms of reengineering code it isn't a good example. Karthick, yes, it's covering the same issue. How did you find out? Because I was also trying to find a topic, but without success.

Answer (score 0):

In the [operator precedence table](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence), `!=` is ahead of `=`.

So the below line:

```
 while(c = fgetc(dtzgr_0) != EOF)
```

is equivalent to:

```
 while(c = (fgetc(dtzgr_0) != EOF))
```

So `c` will be assigned the value of 0 if the return from `fgetc` is not `EOF`.

You have to change the above line to this:

```
 while((c = fgetc(dtzgr_0)) != EOF)
```

Then you will assign the return value from `fgetc` to `c` and only then compare it with `EOF`.

Comment: Thx P.W, the code was given by the trainer and obviously it isn't correct fully. I understand the way you explained the valance of the operators. I also like the operator precedence table.